# How to load a TF Lite Model into Python from a file

Tags: python, tensorflow-lite

I've followed the End-to-End [image classification tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/models/modify/model_maker) for tensorflow lite and have created and saved my model as `'/path/to/model.tflite'`.

What I haven't been able to figure out is how to load it.

I'm looking for some kind of syntax that is similar to this:

```py
from tflite_model_maker import image_classifier
from tflite_model_maker.image_classifier import DataLoader

model = image_classifier.Load('/path/to/model.tflite')
```

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious here. This is definitely not the first place I've looked at. [This](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/inference#load_and_run_a_model_in_python) seems to be the best place for me to find what I need, but the syntax used confuses me.

What do I want to be able to do with the model?

```
test = DataLoader.from_folder('/path/to/testImages')
loss, accuracy = model.evaluate(test)

# A helper function that returns 'red'/'black' depending on if its two input
# parameter matches or not.
def get_label_color(val1, val2):
  if val1 == val2:
    return 'black'
  else:
    return 'red'

# Then plot 100 test images and their predicted labels.
# If a prediction result is different from the label provided label in "test"
# dataset, we will highlight it in red color.
test_data = data

plt.figure(figsize=(20, 20))
predicts = model.predict_top_k(test_data)
for i, (image, label) in enumerate(test_data.gen_dataset().unbatch().take(100)):
  ax = plt.subplot(10, 10, i+1)
  plt.xticks([])
  plt.yticks([])
  plt.grid(False)
  plt.imshow(image.numpy(), cmap=plt.cm.gray)

  predict_label = predicts[i][0][0]
  color = get_label_color(predict_label,
                          test_data.index_to_label[label.numpy()])
  ax.xaxis.label.set_color(color)
  plt.xlabel('Predicted: %s' % predict_label)
plt.show()
```

From the syntax above it seems the model isn't just a file but is a type/class/method depending on what name is most suitable for python.

Feels like this should only take one line of code but I haven't been able to find it anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to do a simple version of it. The images coming up as a stream doesn't work for me using cv2 with Windows as it does for the pi. So instead I created a webpage in the same directory as this script. This generates an image with the bounding box, using a specified tflite model. This is in no way ideal.

It uses a webcam to get the image and saves the image to the directory the script is run in. It then renames the file so it can be viewed by the webpage I setup to view it.

The majority of this code comes from the TFLite Object Detection [Raspberry Pi sample](https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/tree/master/lite/examples/object_detection/raspberry_pi).

```py
import time, os
from PIL import Image
from tflite_support import metadata
import platform
from typing import List, NamedTuple
import json
import cv2 as cv2
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

Interpreter = tf.lite.Interpreter
load_delegate = tf.lite.experimental.load_delegate

class ObjectDetectorOptions(NamedTuple):
  """A config to initialize an object detector."""

  enable_edgetpu: bool = False
  """Enable the model to run on EdgeTPU."""

  label_allow_list: List[str] = None
  """The optional allow list of labels."""

  label_deny_list: List[str] = None
  """The optional deny list of labels."""

  max_results: int = -1
  """The maximum number of top-scored detection results to return."""

  num_threads: int = 1
  """The number of CPU threads to be used."""

  score_threshold: float = 0.0
  """The score threshold of detection results to return."""


class Rect(NamedTuple):
  """A rectangle in 2D space."""
  left: float
  top: float
  right: float
  bottom: float


class Category(NamedTuple):
  """A result of a classification task."""
  label: str
  score: float
  index: int


class Detection(NamedTuple):
  """A detected object as the result of an ObjectDetector."""
  bounding_box: Rect
  categories: List[Category]


def edgetpu_lib_name():
  """Returns the library name of EdgeTPU in the current platform."""
  return {
      'Darwin': 'libedgetpu.1.dylib',
      'Linux': 'libedgetpu.so.1',
      'Windows': 'edgetpu.dll',
  }.get(platform.system(), None)


class ObjectDetector:
  """A wrapper class for a TFLite object detection model."""

  _OUTPUT_LOCATION_NAME = 'location'
  _OUTPUT_CATEGORY_NAME = 'category'
  _OUTPUT_SCORE_NAME = 'score'
  _OUTPUT_NUMBER_NAME = 'number of detections'

  def __init__(
      self,
      model_path: str,
      options: ObjectDetectorOptions = ObjectDetectorOptions()
  ) -> None:
    """Initialize a TFLite object detection model.
    Args:
        model_path: Path to the TFLite model.
        options: The config to initialize an object detector. (Optional)
    Raises:
        ValueError: If the TFLite model is invalid.
        OSError: If the current OS isn't supported by EdgeTPU.
    """

    # Load metadata from model.
    displayer = metadata.MetadataDisplayer.with_model_file(model_path)

    # Save model metadata for preprocessing later.
    model_metadata = json.loads(displayer.get_metadata_json())
    process_units = model_metadata['subgraph_metadata'][0]['input_tensor_metadata'][0]['process_units']
    mean = 0.0
    std = 1.0
    for option in process_units:
      if option['options_type'] == 'NormalizationOptions':
        mean = option['options']['mean'][0]
        std = option['options']['std'][0]
    self._mean = mean
    self._std = std

    # Load label list from metadata.
    file_name = displayer.get_packed_associated_file_list()[0]
    label_map_file = displayer.get_associated_file_buffer(file_name).decode()
    label_list = list(filter(lambda x: len(x) > 0, label_map_file.splitlines()))
    self._label_list = label_list

    # Initialize TFLite model.
    if options.enable_edgetpu:
      if edgetpu_lib_name() is None:
        raise OSError("The current OS isn't supported by Coral EdgeTPU.")
      interpreter = Interpreter(
          model_path=model_path,
          experimental_delegates=[load_delegate(edgetpu_lib_name())],
          num_threads=options.num_threads)
    else:
      interpreter = Interpreter(
          model_path=model_path, num_threads=options.num_threads)

    interpreter.allocate_tensors()
    input_detail = interpreter.get_input_details()[0]

    # From TensorFlow 2.6, the order of the outputs become undefined.
    # Therefore we need to sort the tensor indices of TFLite outputs and to know
    # exactly the meaning of each output tensor. For example, if
    # output indices are [601, 599, 598, 600], tensor names and indices aligned
    # are:
    #   - location: 598
    #   - category: 599
    #   - score: 600
    #   - detection_count: 601
    # because of the op's ports of TFLITE_DETECTION_POST_PROCESS
    # (https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/a4fe268ea084e7d323133ed7b986e0ae259a2bc7/tensorflow/lite/kernels/detection_postprocess.cc#L47-L50).
    sorted_output_indices = sorted(
        [output['index'] for output in interpreter.get_output_details()])
    self._output_indices = {
        self._OUTPUT_LOCATION_NAME: sorted_output_indices[0],
        self._OUTPUT_CATEGORY_NAME: sorted_output_indices[1],
        self._OUTPUT_SCORE_NAME: sorted_output_indices[2],
        self._OUTPUT_NUMBER_NAME: sorted_output_indices[3],
    }

    self._input_size = input_detail['shape'][2], input_detail['shape'][1]
    self._is_quantized_input = input_detail['dtype'] == np.uint8
    self._interpreter = interpreter
    self._options = options

  def detect(self, input_image: np.ndarray) -> List[Detection]:
    """Run detection on an input image.
    Args:
        input_image: A [height, width, 3] RGB image. Note that height and width
          can be anything since the image will be immediately resized according
          to the needs of the model within this function.
    Returns:
        A Person instance.
    """
    image_height, image_width, _ = input_image.shape

    input_tensor = self._preprocess(input_image)

    self._set_input_tensor(input_tensor)
    self._interpreter.invoke()

    # Get all output details
    boxes = self._get_output_tensor(self._OUTPUT_LOCATION_NAME)
    classes = self._get_output_tensor(self._OUTPUT_CATEGORY_NAME)
    scores = self._get_output_tensor(self._OUTPUT_SCORE_NAME)
    count = int(self._get_output_tensor(self._OUTPUT_NUMBER_NAME))

    return self._postprocess(boxes, classes, scores, count, image_width,
                             image_height)

  def _preprocess(self, input_image: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
    """Preprocess the input image as required by the TFLite model."""

    # Resize the input
    input_tensor = cv2.resize(input_image, self._input_size)

    # Normalize the input if it's a float model (aka. not quantized)
    if not self._is_quantized_input:
      input_tensor = (np.float32(input_tensor) - self._mean) / self._std

    # Add batch dimension
    input_tensor = np.expand_dims(input_tensor, axis=0)

    return input_tensor

  def _set_input_tensor(self, image):
    """Sets the input tensor."""
    tensor_index = self._interpreter.get_input_details()[0]['index']
    input_tensor = self._interpreter.tensor(tensor_index)()[0]
    input_tensor[:, :] = image

  def _get_output_tensor(self, name):
    """Returns the output tensor at the given index."""
    output_index = self._output_indices[name]
    tensor = np.squeeze(self._interpreter.get_tensor(output_index))
    return tensor

  def _postprocess(self, boxes: np.ndarray, classes: np.ndarray,
                   scores: np.ndarray, count: int, image_width: int,
                   image_height: int) -> List[Detection]:
    """Post-process the output of TFLite model into a list of Detection objects.
    Args:
        boxes: Bounding boxes of detected objects from the TFLite model.
        classes: Class index of the detected objects from the TFLite model.
        scores: Confidence scores of the detected objects from the TFLite model.
        count: Number of detected objects from the TFLite model.
        image_width: Width of the input image.
        image_height: Height of the input image.
    Returns:
        A list of Detection objects detected by the TFLite model.
    """
    results = []

    # Parse the model output into a list of Detection entities.
    for i in range(count):
      if scores[i] >= self._options.score_threshold:
        y_min, x_min, y_max, x_max = boxes[i]
        bounding_box = Rect(
            top=int(y_min * image_height),
            left=int(x_min * image_width),
            bottom=int(y_max * image_height),
            right=int(x_max * image_width))
        class_id = int(classes[i])
        category = Category(
            score=scores[i],
            label=self._label_list[class_id],  # 0 is reserved for background
            index=class_id)
        result = Detection(bounding_box=bounding_box, categories=[category])
        results.append(result)

    # Sort detection results by score ascending
    sorted_results = sorted(
        results,
        key=lambda detection: detection.categories[0].score,
        reverse=True)

    # Filter out detections in deny list
    filtered_results = sorted_results
    if self._options.label_deny_list is not None:
      filtered_results = list(
          filter(
              lambda detection: detection.categories[0].label not in self.
              _options.label_deny_list, filtered_results))

    # Keep only detections in allow list
    if self._options.label_allow_list is not None:
      filtered_results = list(
          filter(
              lambda detection: detection.categories[0].label in self._options.
              label_allow_list, filtered_results))

    # Only return maximum of max_results detection.
    if self._options.max_results > 0:
      result_count = min(len(filtered_results), self._options.max_results)
      filtered_results = filtered_results[:result_count]

    return filtered_results


_MARGIN = 10  # pixels
_ROW_SIZE = 10  # pixels
_FONT_SIZE = 1
_FONT_THICKNESS = 1
_TEXT_COLOR = (0, 0, 255)  # red


def visualize(
    image: np.ndarray,
    detections: List[Detection],
) -> np.ndarray:
  """Draws bounding boxes on the input image and return it.
  Args:
    image: The input RGB image.
    detections: The list of all "Detection" entities to be visualize.
  Returns:
    Image with bounding boxes.
  """
  for detection in detections:
    # Draw bounding_box
    start_point = detection.bounding_box.left, detection.bounding_box.top
    end_point = detection.bounding_box.right, detection.bounding_box.bottom
    cv2.rectangle(image, start_point, end_point, _TEXT_COLOR, 3)

    # Draw label and score
    category = detection.categories[0]
    class_name = category.label
    probability = round(category.score, 2)
    result_text = class_name + ' (' + str(probability) + ')'
    text_location = (_MARGIN + detection.bounding_box.left,
                     _MARGIN + _ROW_SIZE + detection.bounding_box.top)
    cv2.putText(image, result_text, text_location, cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN,
                _FONT_SIZE, _TEXT_COLOR, _FONT_THICKNESS)

  return image


# ---------------------------------- #
#    This is where the custom code starts
# ---------------------------------- #
# Load the TFLite model
TFLITE_MODEL_PATH='object.tflite'
DETECTION_THRESHOLD = 0.5 # 50% threshold required before identifying

options = ObjectDetectorOptions(
      num_threads=4,
      score_threshold=DETECTION_THRESHOLD,
)

# Close camera if already open
try:
    cap.release()
except:
    print("",end="") # do nothing

detector = ObjectDetector(model_path=TFLITE_MODEL_PATH, options=options)
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0) #webcam
counter = 0 # Store many times model has run
while cap.isOpened():
    success, image = cap.read()
    if not success:
      sys.exit(
          'ERROR: Unable to read from webcam. Please verify your webcam settings.'
      )

    image = cv2.flip(image, 1)
    # Convert the image from BGR to RGB as required by the TFLite model.
    rgb_image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

    #image.thumbnail((512, 512), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    image_np = np.asarray(image)
    # Run object detection estimation using the model.
    detections = detector.detect(image_np)
    # Draw keypoints and edges on input image
    image_np = visualize(image_np, detections)



    if counter == 10: # <- Change this to decide how many iterations
        cap.release()
        break
    image_np = cv2.cvtColor(image_np, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    plt.imsave('tmp.jpg',image_np) # Saves the image
    os.replace("tmp.jpg", "web.jpg",) # Renames it for the webpage
    counter += 1
    print(counter)
cap.release()
```

Here's the HTML for the document placed in the same directory as the python file, I saved it as index.html and opened in the browser while running the python script above.

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Object Detection</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Object Detection</h1>
<p>This displays images saved during detection process</p>
<canvas id="x" width="700px" height="500px"></canvas>
<script>
var newImage = new Image();

newImage.src = "web.jpg";
var canvas = document.getElementById("x");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

newImage.onload = function() {
    context.drawImage(newImage, 0, 0);
    console.log("trigger")
    setTimeout(timedRefresh, 1000);
};

function timedRefresh() {
    // just change src attribute, will always trigger the onload callback
    try {
        newImage.src = ("web.jpg#" + new Date().getTime());
    }catch(e){
        console.log(e);
    }
}
setTimeout(timedRefresh, 100);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

It's incredibly slow, not ideal in many ways and probably breaks many good coding conventions. It was only used locally, would definitely not use this for a production environment nor recommend its use. Just needed a quick proof of concept and this worked for that.